# Cantor set is zero measure but has finite fractal dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, cantor-set

I am from physics community. Recently I am quite confused by Cantor set. The analysis book tells me that Cantor set has measure zero. But meanwhile, you can use small box to cover it, and obtain the [box-counting dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) to be $\log_3 2$. Is there some controversy here ?

Comment: The analysis book is talking about measure in dimension $1.$ Think about a line in the plane -- its planar measure is $0$ but its linear measure is infinite. The Cantor (middle thirds) set has $0$ measure in any dimension greater than $\log_3 2$ and infinite measure in any dimension less than $\log_3 2,$ and some finite measure whose value I don't know (it might be $1)$ in dimension $\log_3 2.$

Comment: I'm confused - why do you think there should be a controversy? Can you explain why these two facts seem contradictory to you?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I am confused because I feel that a set is measure zero means its volume is zero in some sense, like a 2 dimensional plane in 3 dimensional space. But apparently, I just need to read more to figure out what Lebesgue measure is.